# Writing text in png image

Tags: ios, objective-c, png

Hopefully it will be a duplicate question, but I am really stuck in writing into png data chunks. Can someone help me how to get headers from data, in objective-C? Here is the information [Section 4.7.2 , c part, Textual Information](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11iTXt).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not need to care about png data chunks, just have a try with the code below:

```
   //load target image, then draw text on the target image
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"targetImage.png"];
    NSString * text = @"Watermark!";
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(20, 30);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Convert UIImage object into NSData (a wrapper for a stream of bytes) formatted according to PNG spec
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

    //Save imageDate to disk as a png file
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *imageSubdirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"watermarkFolderName"];
    NSString *filePath = [imageSubdirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"watermark.png"];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: would you please like code of reading text from the image, the reverse of the above code? I will check both these and let you know if they fullfill my requirement. Thanks

Comment: "reading text from the image" is something related to OCR(Optical Character Recognition).In my opinion, it is easy to write text into image, but recognition is hard and inaccurately.

Comment: Ok thanks brother, Have you look on the link given above in my question? Can we read write in that way in IOS?

Comment: This seems to answer a very different question. This explains how to draw text on a bitmap image (rendered as pixels), the OP wants to embed textual _metadata_ on the image, which is not to be displayed but to be retrieved as such.

Comment: @leonbloy , Exactly I want to "embed textual metadata on the image". Can you help me?  Thanks